# How to setup shadowsocks client on centos 6.6?

Tags: centos, software-installation, shadowsocks

shadowsocks is working well on my mac.

I have tried a lot of [tutorials](https://medium.com/@ATheCoder/how-to-setup-shadowsocks-client-on-centos-f7f104a54363) to setup shadowsocks client on centos 6.6 in vm fusion, none of them work.

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum -y install python-pip
sudo yum -y install libsodium
sudo pip install https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/archive/master.zip -U
sudo nano /etc/shadowsocks.json
# paste the same configuration that works well on my mac
sudo sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json -d start
```

So far, everything goes well. `curl 127.0.0.1:1080 http://httpbin.org/ip` returns the IP successfully though, `--socks5` param produces

> couldn't connect to host

with this configuration:

[image]

i've tried to set "No proxy for" as localhost, 127.0.0.1 or empty, none of them worked.

Firefox cannot access anything.

Any clues?

this is not about [shadowsocks-qt5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/517284/351344).

Answer (score 0):

According to your tutorial , your shadowsocks client ( ss-local ) exposes a SOCKS-5 proxy , and you can use that SOCKS-5 proxy for all your connections in Firefox , but as it shows in your screenshot , you are using the HTTP proxy section of your Firefox , just fill out the SOCKS5 section and remove HTTP proxy section on your Firefox proxy settings and it should work just fine  , but if you you need to use the HTTP proxy on port 1080 , you can use the Qt5 version
the Qt5 version is working very well for me and you have greater control over your proxy settings  .

https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-qt5/wiki/Installation

it has a nice GUI and it opens a http/s proxy on port 1080 that can be used as you global proxy or Firefox proxy .

Comment: https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-qt5

Comment: Welcome to U&L! This post doesn't provide and answer to the question so it should be posted in the comments section bellow the question. Thank's for contribute!

Comment: this seems to not be working for me, because i am doing this from China, I posted another question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/517284/351344 about shadowsocks-qt5